# Menu setActionView(view) to xml

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, action

In onCreateOptionsMenu I'm setting an action view with:

```
MenuItem item = ..
item.setActionView(action_view)
item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

and it works ok. But I want to move this to my xml menu and I can't seem to make it show. It only shows up the title. I tried many versions, like:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/myPackage.myClass" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item"
        yourApp:actionViewClass="action_view"
        android:showAsAction="always" or youtApp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="title"
    </item>
```

The problem must be it getting to the action_view variable, but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Did you inflate the menubar?

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_name, menu);

   mMenu = menu;
   if(mMenu != null){
       MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(R.id.item_id);
       if(item != null){
           item.setVisible(false);
       }
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Also do you have `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` @onCreate() function?

Comment: I inflated it cause I have other normal menu items, but I didn't have that setVisible section. If I add that, I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131492922, size is 3

Comment: my bad...in that case you need to use `menu.findItem(R.id.item_id)

Comment: it runs, but still doesn't show anything. Probably I should have mentioned that the other normal items show properly. I don't have a fragment for setHasOptionsMenu

Comment: yourapp:showAsAction="always" is wrong... try using android:showAsaction="always" or add this line also (if not using support library)

Comment: turns out it shows only the title. it doesn't get the action_view variable

Comment: So start the intent @ onOptionsItemSelected

Comment: You didn't specify icon parameter so it shows you the title. if you want icon use: android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" or something similar

Comment: action_view is a view that keeps changing, not an icon. that's the whole reason why I use actionViewClass

Comment: I know that...what i meant is that u still maybe need to add icon if you don't want the text. maybe with text your actionbar doesn't have space. anyhow have a look at `http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html`

Comment: tried with icon or without title and icon, still nothing. it doesn't get to the view variable. maybe the problem is with xmlns:yourApp

Comment: change xmlns:yourApp to: `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: still nothing. don't i have to provide the class where action_view is?

Comment: Of course you have to: for example `yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: tried with package.class.variable and still no luck :)

Comment: copy and paste android developer example using the link i gave you ( the example with actionView of course and see if it's working...if yes then go from there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item:
    // Write your action_view here

    break; 
    case R.id.your_other_item_id:
    //Your other Menu item logic

    break;
    }       
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);       
}
```

Comment: of course i have onOptionsItemSelected. the problem is that the item doesn't show, not that it doesn't do something